# Handling WM_ events in a windowless C# process

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, wndproc

I've been looking around for quite a while, and can't seem to find a good way to do this.

Basically I have a C# process using WPF (which has no visible window), that I need to handle WM_ events in (such as `WM_CLOSE` or `WM_DESTROY` for example; so that I can elegantly shutdown when a user chooses to log off or restart their machine).

There are a number of solutions I've seen out there that suggest using `System.Windows.InteropServices` to call `AddHook` and provide it a pointer to a function that then becomes the `WndProc`. The problem with this is, as far as I can tell, it depends on the window actually being visible (and in this case there is no window).

Another way that's suggested but doesn't work is to override the `WndProc` method of a WinForm, but this process has no visible forms or windows.

I've also found things referring to a Message-only Window. Some kind of invisible window that still receives WM_ events. From what I've seen, this is only available in a `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms` assembly. I added a reference to this assembly in my project and subclassed MessageWindow as indicated at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow.aspx but it still seems to not work. The breakpoints inside the WndProc are not being hit.

Any clue?

Comment: It's been a while since I've played at that level but I seem to recall using 0 for the HWND (which I seem to recall reading somewhere was the desktop's HWND). I'd have to dig through my archives to verify, but I'm almost certain this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are asking- if you don't have a window, how could your application receive a window message (considering that messages are sent to a window's handle).

That's like saying "how can I receive email without having an email address?"

Michael Entin covers windows' behavior during shutdown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2008/04/04/application-termination-when-user-logs-off.aspx).

I am 99% sure that all processes running in a user's session are automatically closed when the user logs off anyway, so this shouldn't be an issue.  If you really must handle this window message, you can create a hidden window as per [Any way to create a hidden main window in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683896/any-way-to-create-a-hidden-main-window-in-c)

Comment: Chris is right. So long as your app doesn't prevent itself from being shut-down when asked, it should close cleanly. The next question, therefore, is why write your app as a windowless background app rather than a Windows Service?

Comment: @RichardTurner - How would you expect a windows service to be able to hook Windows events?

Comment: @M.Babcock he doesn't mention handling windows key and mouse events, other than `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_DESTROY` (which presumably he only needs to shut down the application, which as I point out isn't necessary)

Comment: @ChrisShain - Editted. I read too far into the question. I'm not saying your question is wrong, but if the OP needs to do it this way (for some unknown corner case) then a Windows Service won't help either.

Comment: @ChrisShain - Thanks for the information. The link about shutdown process is interesting, but he specifically omits discussing my situation, which is a ui-less application, which I'm (obviously) more interested in. Also, yes I currently only care about WM_CLOSE, WM_DESTROY, WM_QUERYENDSESSION (possibly), and WM_ENDSESSION (as it would appear from the article you linked).

The solution for a hidden main window in C# seems to be a kludge really (unfortunately), just creating an off-screen window with no task bar entry. =(

Comment: The situation might have changed in the past 5 years and 3 months, but why not just create a hidden window? The hidden window can then get all the windows events you like. Unless you are making a CLI, this shouldn't cause any issues...